# ctools table component conditional formatting

Tags: pentaho, conditional-formatting

I have no idea if this is the correct forum to ask this question, but I figured I would give it a go - does anyone use Pentaho Ctools? I am trying to apply conditional formatting to column 8 of my table component, but so far no available. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function f(){  
    this.setAddInOptions("numeric","formattedText",function(statusReport){
        var days = statusReport.value;
        if(statusREport.colIndex == 8)
        if(days <=30){
            return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:green'>"+v+"</span>"; } };
        }
         else {
            return { textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:red'>"+v+"</span>"; }  };
            }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre Execution Function:

```
function f(){  
//conditional coloring of cells 
    this.setAddInOptions("colType","formattedText",function(cell_data){
        var days = cell_data.value;
        if(cell_data.colIdx == 7)
        {
            if(!cell_data.value) //checking the null possibility
            {
                this.value = '00000';
            }
        }
        if(days > 30){
            return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:#FF0000'>"+v+"</span>"; } };
        }
         else if(days <= 30) {
            return { textFormat: function(v, st) { return "<span style='color:#000000'>"+v+"</span>"; }  };
            }
      })   ;  
}
```

You also have to update the Column Types in Advanced Properties - make the regular column types "string" or whatever they are and change the formatted column to "formattedText".